# Save result from async function to global variable

Tags: arrays, swift, function

I have a function with JSON response. At this moment I'm using completion method, but I want to use JSON array in another View. How to save this Array as global variable, or advise another way to use this array in second View.(And if it real, I want to get rid of this completion method and use just massive without all times recall the function with completion, because to receive a response I need wait like about 5sec).

```
    func LTE1800(_ completion: @escaping ([[String]]) -> ()) {
    let myURLAdress = "myURL"
    let myURL = URL(string: myURLAdress)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myURL!) { (data, 
   response, error) in
        guard let dataResponse = data,
            error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response 
   Error")
                return }
        do{
            let jsonResponse = try 
  JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:dataResponse, options: []) as! 
   [String:Any]
              guard let jsonArray = jsonResponse["aaData"] as? 
   [[String]] else {
                return
            }
            completion(jsonArray)

        }

        catch let parsingError {
            print("Error", parsingError)
        }

    }
    task.resume()

  }
```

Comment: Put JSON method in its own class. Call this method inside your views, and use your completion method to handle what you want to do. Is this not what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you shouldn't be using mutable global variables in swift. What you *should* be doing is calling the network request then on completion, update the UI as needed. One common pattern to pass data around views is the delegate pattern.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/477-design-patterns-on-ios-using-swift-part-1-2

Comment: Ok, thanks. @Mocha One more question, can I put data from jsonArray into database(core data), if it really, could you say how can I make it

Comment: You can store anything into core data (But you might need to convert it into json string and back to object). Once you convert the json into a swift object, you can use any core data tutorial. There are many tutorials online.. 

https://www.raywenderlich.com/7569-getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial